# List index out of range parsing CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement

For my school assignment I have created a program which checks for an EMAIL and PASSWORD found in rows 0 and 1 in a csv file which match up, and will then print some information about that user from rows 2-6. However, I believe this is not necessarily any cause of my problem.

The problem is the else statement.

When a user enters both their EMAIL and PASSWORD correctly the system will print their information. However if the EMAIl and PASSWORD entered don't match up with the ones in the CSV file, I attempted to create an ELSE statement that would print 'Your email or password is incorrect'

However, instead, I would receive this error:

```
line 12, in <module>
    if email_1 in row[0] and pass_1 in row[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since I'm new to python, I'm not sure why this is happening, but I don't reckon it is to do with the code above since when details are entered correctly, the program will print the information.

I have tried to make the ELSE statement work without the use of assigning a variable to be TRUE or FALSE, but nor did that work, exactly the same issue. It's just the ELSE statement which it doesn't seem to be recognising.

Code:

```
import csv

email_pass = False
email_1 = raw_input('What is your email? :')
pass_1 = raw_input('What is your password? :')
with open('DATAFILE.csv', "rb") as csvfile:
    my_content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_content:
        if email_1 in row[0] and pass_1 in row[1]:
            email_pass = True
            if email_pass == True:
                print row[2:6]
                break
            else:
                print 'Your EMAIL or PASSWORD is incorrect'
```

Comment: add a `print row` before the `if email_1 in row...` line to see what does the problematic row have.

Comment: If you had different indentation, this would look like the old "iterate over a thing, set a flag if you find something, then after the loop is over, do something based on the state of the flag" recipe. But you'd have to remove two levels of indentation from every line starting at `if email_pass == True`, and you'd have to get rid of the `break`.

Comment: What the error actually means is that there was no second column in the row you were trying to process. I recommend looking over your CSV file to see if there are any rows (such as the last one) that don't conform to the standard appearance you're looking for.

Comment: also `if email_1 in row[0]` only checks if email_1 is a substring of row[0], not if they are equal. for instance `@ in me@example.org` would evaluate to `True`, which is probably not something you want. Same thing for the password.

Comment: Even better (from a cracking perspective) would be for the user to simply hit Enter for their username and password, since the empty string is `in` any string. `==` really is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `else` statement has a wrong indentation. Where you put it, it well never be reached because you put it inside the block `if email_1 in row[0] and pass_1 in row[1]:`

Just remove the four spaces and it should work.

The `email_pass` is useless. Do you understand how the conditional structure works?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. An `else` block that never gets evaluated won't produce an exception, and the exception in the question refers to a different line.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but the indentation issue was so obvious that I wanted to point it out.

Comment: If it's not an answer, post it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks! :) Superb! The only reason I used email_pass was to see whether that would resolve my problem, but turns out, like you said, it was the indentation! :)

Comment: @user2560053 I have tried removing the email_pass, it seems the program doesn't work without it. Sorry, I'm new to Python, am I making a mistake? Here's the code: http://gyazo.com/43460279b4cc5daf2b48008a52961b31

Answer (score 0):

The probem in your code is not (yet) related to your `else` statement.

As you can see the error happens when it tries to evaluate the condition for the first `if`.

This means it can never reach the else because there is another error to take care of before.

You need to check the values of your variables to be sure of what you really want.

Comment: I don't think `row` is a string, so it doesn't have a `split` method. Iterating over a `csv.reader` gives you a list of items in each iteration.

Comment: Ah, true, I didn't notice. However, he should check the value of row and what he expects from it.